# I want to update live canvas line chart by json data

Tags: javascript, json, ajax, canvas

There is an issue with my code: the chart doesn't update. I'm using canvasJS chart, I’m a newbie in that area.

```
<%@ page language=”java” contentType=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″ pageEncoding=”UTF-8″%>
<%@ page import=”java.util.*” %>

<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv=”Content-Type” content=”text/html; charset=UTF-8″>
  <script src=”https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js”></script>
  <script src=”https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js”></script>
  <script type=”text/javascript”>
    var dataPoints = [];
    var chart;
    $.getJSON(‘http: //localhost:8080/SpringREST/rasp/json’, function(data) {
    $.each(data, function(key, value) {
      dataPoints.push({
        x: (value)[“creation_time”],
        y: Number(value[“temp”])
      });
    }); chart = new CanvasJS.Chart(“chartContainer”, {
      title: {
        text: ”Live Chart with dataPoints from External JSON”
      },
      zoomEnabled: true,
      axisX: {
        scaleBreaks: {
          autoCalculate: true,
          maxNumberOfAutoBreaks: 5,
          collapsibleThreshold: “15 % ”
        },
      },
      zoomType: “xy”,
      //backgroundColor: “#bdcfed”,
      animationEnabled: true,
      animationDuration: 5000,
      exportEnabled: true,
      theme: “dark1”,
      data: [{
        showInLegend: true,
        legendText: “Temperature”,
        markerType: “circle”,
        markerSize: “3”,
        markerColor: “red”,
        xValueType: “dateTime”,
        xValueFormatString: “YYYY - MM - DD HH: mm: ss”,
        toolTipContent: “x: {
          x
        },
        y: {
          y
        }”,
        type: “line”,
        dataPoints: dataPoints,
      }]
    }); chart.render(); updateChart();
    });

    function updateChart() {
      $.getJSON(‘http: //localhost:8080/SpringREST/rasp/json’, function(data) {
        dataPoints = []; $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          dataPoints.push({
            x: (value[“creation_time”]),
            y: Number(value[“temp”]),

          });
        }); console.log(chart.options) chart.render();
      });
    }

    setTimeout(function() {
      updateChart()
    }, 1000);
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <br/>
  <!– Just so that JSFiddle’s Result label doesn’t overlap the Chart –>
  <div id=”chartContainer” style=”height: 360px; width: 100%;”></div>
</body>

</html>
```

My JSON data :

```
[{
  "creation_time": 1564828719000,
  "id": 18443,
  "action": "",
  "com_Z_Axis": "-29.0",
  "humi": "84.4",
  "com_X_Axis": "-27.0",
  "com_Y_Axis": "0.0",
  "pressure": "989.3",
  "gyro_Y_Axis": "0.0",
  "acc_Y_Axis": "0.0",
  "pitch_X_Axis": "351.0",
  "temp": "24.5",
  "yaw_Z_Axis": "191.0",
  "gyro_Z_Axis": "0.0",
  "acc_Z_Axis": "1.0",
  "gyro_X_Axis": "-0.0",
  "acc_X_Axis": "0.0",
  "stability": "stable",
  "roll_Y_Axis": "6.0",
  "direction": ""
}]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[setTimeout method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) calls a function or evaluates an expression after a specified number of milliseconds (only once) whereas [setInterval method](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) calls a function or evaluates an expression at specified intervals (in milliseconds). Changing setTimeout to setInterval should work fine in this case.

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv='Content-Type' content='text/html; charset=UTF-8'>
    <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
    <script src='https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js'></script>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
      var dataPoints = [];
      var chart;
      $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/sysrl', function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(key, value) {
          dataPoints.push({
            x: (value)['creation_time'],
            y: Number(value['temp'])
          });
        }); chart = new CanvasJS.Chart('chartContainer', {
          title: {
            text: 'Live Chart with dataPoints from External JSON'
          },
          zoomEnabled: true,
          axisX: {
            scaleBreaks: {
              autoCalculate: true,
              maxNumberOfAutoBreaks: 5,
              collapsibleThreshold: '15 % '
            },
          },
          zoomType: 'xy',
          //backgroundColor: '#bdcfed',
          animationEnabled: true,
          animationDuration: 5000,
          exportEnabled: true,
          data: [{
            showInLegend: true,
            legendText: 'Temperature',
            markerType: 'circle',
            markerSize: '3',
            markerColor: 'red',
            xValueType: 'dateTime',
            xValueFormatString: 'YYYY - MM - DD HH: mm: ss',
            toolTipContent: 'x: {x}, y: {y}',
            type: 'line',
            dataPoints: dataPoints,
          }]
        }); chart.render(); updateChart();
      });

      function updateChart() {
        $.getJSON('https://api.myjson.com/bins/sysrl', function(data) {
          dataPoints = []; $.each(data, function(key, value) {
            dataPoints.push({
              x: (value['creation_time']),
              y: Number(value['temp']),

            });
          });
        });
      }

      setInterval(function() {
        updateChart()
      }, 1000);
    </script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div id='chartContainer' style='height: 360px; width: 100%;'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I tried but not getting any success basically my chart is render properly by json data, but i want that my chart dynamically render json data every second when new data come in json object. I fetching two data from json object first is temp and second is time. please help.

Comment: JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/5tj4v6wd/ It seems to be working fine. If you are facing any issue share JSFiddle along with sample data. Also check the browser console for any errors

Comment: this is my code and json data on jsfiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/shyam1992/d9aL2cnv/10/

Comment: Rendering properly but not real time chart update when data is coming.

Comment: As you are updating dataPoints by reading JSON every second, chart gets updated with new set of dataPoints on every update. If the JSON file is not updated chart won't get updated as chart just renders whatever data you will be providing. But chart won't animate on every update - as CanvasJS Charts animate only on initial render as of now.